# auto refreshing worksheet then pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble getting specific columns to refresh when new entries are entered via a user form and to have my pivot tables update automatically.

I've created a userform that dumps data into a specific sheet which is the data source for some pivot tables that I've created. When the information transfers into the worksheet numerical values are read as text but I created a module to transfer those values into a numerical format. The problem is that I have to be on the data source page for the conversion to work, so I was wondering if it's possible to have the columns and then the pivot table be autorefreshed as soon as  someone hits the submit button?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    MsgBox "Submitted!", 0, "Message"
    Unload ProjectCheckIn

Dim TargetRow As Integer


TargetRow = Sheets("Backend").Range("B3").Value + 1


Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 0).Value = ComboBox1
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 1).Value = ComboBox22
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 3).Value = ComboBox2
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 7).Value = TextBox1
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 8).Value = TextBox2
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 2).Value = ComboBox23
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 4).Value = ComboBox7
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 5).Value = ComboBox12
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 6).Value = ComboBox17
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload ProjectCheckIn
Run ([Numberconversion])
Run ([Numberconversion2])
End Sub

Private Sub Project_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` at the end of `CommandButton1_Click()`.
Also, did you try using `CDbl()` when transferring the selections to the cells?  For example:

```
Sheets("Data").Range("Name").Offset(TargetRow, 6).Value = CDbl(ComboBox17.Value)
```

That could resolve the issue of them being passed as text.